# Compare two table in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have two django model, `User` and `Follow`.
In the `Follow` table, I have two attribute `a` and `b` which means `a following b`. 
`User` table is just the django.contrib.auth.User

Let say I am in `user A` homepage, and `A` is following `B`, `C` and not following `D`.

I want to list all the username in `A`'s homepage and highlighting those `A` is following.

In this case `B`, `C` should be highlighted and D should not be highlighted.

I was thinking about (pseudocode)

```
for user in users :
    for follow in Following:
        if user.username == follow.username:
             flag=true
             break
     if flag:
          #print color <p>user.username</p>
     else
          #print normal..
```

But I dun think django template allow me to do this. 
Is there any other ways to do this?

Here is my code in django template

```
  {% for user in all_user %}
      {% for follower in followers %}
          {% ifequal user.username follower.follow.username %}
              <p class="following">{{user.username}}</p>
          {% endifequal %}
      {% endfor %}
      <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

This will duplicate the user that 'A' is following.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I would approach this by doing what you have done here, and by passing the variable "flag" to your template, as well as the rest of the objects.

```
{% if flag == True %}
    <do whatever>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an attribute to the user in your for loop, then retrieve that in the template.

```
for user in users :
    for follow in Following:
        if user.username == follow.username:
             user.followed = True
             break
```

Then in your template

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.followed %}
        ....
    {% else %}
        ....
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You mean add one more attr into the `Follow` model? That means I have to include all pairs of user in my database?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought that the part where you figure out if the user is followed was already taken care of (and that your first example was more or less pseudocode). My solution is more about a clean way of passing the data through to the template (since you said I don't think django template will allow me to do this).